# Dijkstra algorithm for 3D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I made **three-dimensional array** and I want to search the **shortest way from point y to point x.** I don't know what i should use algorithm (Dijkstra or A*). 
Move can be - up down left right

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][][] Station = new String[5][5][5];
        String[] p = {"I","II","III","IV","V"};
        String[] s = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
        String[] po = {"1","2","3","4","5"};

        fillArray(Station,p,s,po);

        String x = Station[3][0][2];
        String y = Station[3][0][2];
    }

    static void fillArray(String[][][] Station, String[] p,String[] s,String[] po) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                for (int g = 0; g < 5; g++) {
                    Station[i][k][g] = p[i];
                    Station[i][k][g] += s[k];
                    Station[i][k][g] += po[g];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing I want to print in a console the shortest way(eg. IIIa2,IIa2)

Comment: Is `up down left right` enough for three dimensions? What is your distance/cost function? Shortest path beginning and ending where?

Comment: I dont get it, if you just have four move types, how is this 3D? you must have back and forward too!

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. Yes Move can be - up down left right back and forward !

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you trying to find is a so called [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), which can be done by several algorithms (e.g. [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)).

Even though your current description of movements implies just a 2-dimensional space, an other problem is, that you didn't state what "shortest way" mean. If you just want to get from point A (x1,y1,z1) to point B (x2,y2,z3) without any obstacles and/or weighting of movements (e.g. moving in X uses more "power"), the fastest way to get from A to B is just to move diagonally (approximated by consecutive movement in X, Y, Z) until you reach the level of your designated location.

If you have any restrictions in movement, e.g. by obstacles, you have to map the allowed movements of each point to vertices of an additional "searching" graph. The article of Dijkstras algorithm has a good [illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#mediaviewer/File:Dijkstras_progress_animation.gif) for that type of searching. Note that the search will be very time and memory consuming because every vertex has to be checked, if you want to find the real *minimum*.